# Wordpress alongside Symfony - Error 404 page not found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

We have a wordpress blog hosted in a different from our web application. For SEO concerns, we decided to rebuild the blog on the same server as our application.
It already has a Apache2 running with the root path directing to our Symfony application /web folder.

We installed Wordpress in var/www/wordpress, set the permissions on this folder for Apache2 and configured the DB connection. The homepage of our wordpress is visible on the /content path (www.mysite.com/content).

For that, I added a single to my existing apache2 conf :
Alias /content /var/www/wordpress

We started building the homepage, uploaded themes, everything works fine. But when we want to add a new page (ie. /content/blog), we get a 404. Resetting the permalinks does nothing. Setting the permalink mode to ?pageId=XXX allows us to see the new page, but that's not what we want.

Did I miss something in my apache configuration ? Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumble upon this looking for an answer, I had to add some configuration to Apache for my site :

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
   Options FollowSymlinks
</Directory>
```